# Autoimplement int range: List<DBInvoiceModel> invoiceRecords = GetInvoiceRecords(100);

Tags: c#

For testing purposes only, I have specified an int range as follows -- so that I could test individual records. Now, I am satisfied with testing, and I need to re-code project to allow it to query all records in queue, not just certain ones that are hard-coded:

```
private string CalculateOrderQueryXML(string key, string accountName)
{
    //TODO: MAKE THE APPLICATION WORK THRU ALL ORDERS NOT SPECIFY A RANGE
    int OrderNoStart = 100;
    int OrderNoEnd = 200;
    string XMLstring = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
```

later in the application, I have a method which also calls this same int, as follows:

```
// Get the invoice records from the database
//TODO: MAKE INVOICE RECORDS WORK THRU ALL RECORDS IN QUEUE, NOT HARD-CODED
List<DBInvoiceModel> invoiceRecords = GetInvoiceRecords(100);
```

Then, the orders are queried as follows:

```
private async Task<string> QueryOrders(string key, string accountName)
{
    string XMLstring = CalculateOrderQueryXML(key, accountName);
    StringContent stringcontent = new StringContent(XMLstring);

    stringcontent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "text/XML";
    HttpResponseMessage response = await http.PostAsync("https://www.example.com/shared/xml/orderquery.rest", stringcontent);

    /*string for response*/
    string ResponseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(ResponseString);

    return xml.OuterXml;

}
```

I would like to be able to execute the program without referencing a value, such as 100 from above, such that the application processes all orders in the queue.

Could anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Currently it is unclear what problem you face and how to resolve it. For example, the next moments are not clear to me. What queue of orders you are talking you about. What problems does first and second code snippets have? How are they related (for example, first code snippet generates `xml` orders using orders from the second code snippet)? Does method `GetInvoiceRecords` read data from the database? What result are you going to achieve? .

Comment: The queue is in the QueryOrders method from above...I added this to my question. There are no errors, everything runs fine as long as I code the order number I want to query or test to update it. The db takes values and updates the order with those values. GetInvoiceRecords reads data from the database. I believe the orders are accessible through the rest url. This is my first time working with rest. I just need to stop hard coding the order number to query, so that all records get queried and also updated. I hope this answers your question and I apologize it was unclear.

Comment: Is there a way to get all orders or order numbers though the rest API you use?

Comment: if there is, I'm not sure how to. The documentation refers to general testing with the rest client with Mozilla Firefox. Do most implementations involving  rest API come with this kind of detailed documentation?

Comment: Are you permitted to share a link to the documentation of the API that you use? If you don't are you able to contact the API developer to know if such API method exists? I think that such API that allows to get `orders` by their `numbers` must contain a method that allows to get list of all `order numbers`. If fhere is such a method in the API, then organizing general testing (without hard coding `order numbers`) is not a difficult task.

Comment: yes, the documentation is available and is public:
https://www.truecommerce.com/sites/default/files/2020-01/xmltools.pdf I queried orderno on the documentation, and the XML paths consistently refer to this: Element XPath:  Path of the XML element, excluding the top level container (which always matches the name of the XML document).  For example, full path of the OrderNoRange/OrderNoStart node in the OrderQueryRequest document is OrderQueryRequest/OrderNoRange/OrderNoStart.  Attributes are denoted by the @ symbol.   Could you clarify to me, is this documentation, in your opinion, typical?

Comment: I don't have enough experience with APIs to tell if this doc is typical or not. But it is quiet clear. I haven't found a way in this API to query range of available order numbers. But according to the doc you can specify only `OrderNoStart` and get all order numbers starting with specified `OrderNoStart`. Is such approach acceptable for you? Also if you use this approach it is important to take into account that API returns maximum only 15 order nodes. Presence of the `NextPage` node in the `OrderQueryReply` tells that there is orders in subsequent pages, and you should also query them.

Comment: thanks for taking time to review this info...I thought that was the case too...